# With tmux on OSX, how can I make command+k clear more gracefully?

Tags: macos, tmux

When I use the terminal in OSX, I frequently use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to clear the screen and scrollback buffer. It's deep in muscle memory.

I've started tinkering with tmux, and one gripe is that <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> wipes the whole screen, panes and all. What I'd like is for it to affect only the focused pane.

Can I somehow configure this behavior?

Answer (score 37):

Configure iTerm2 to send clear command

Preferences -> Keys -> + (add new global shortcut)

- Keyboard shortcut: ⌘+k
- Action: Send text
- value:

> clear\n

Alternatively configure iTerm2 to effectively map ⌘+k to ctrl+l

- Keyboard shortcut: ⌘+k
- Action: Send Hex Code
- value:

> 0x0c

This way you won't see the text flash and the clear command won't pollute your history.

Comment: Simple and elegant solution. Thank you, my friend.

Comment: Beautiful solution! You've made my tmux experience far more enjoyable. Thank you :)

Comment: Just a warning, this will flash the text to the terminal

Comment: This is great, but it relies on the `clear`command and therefore won't work while inside irb or rails console.

Comment: Question was about terminal not iterm.

Answer (score 20):

You can use <kbd>prefix</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, after the <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, to redraw the tmux window.

If you can break the habit, a normal <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> works normally per pane.

Comment: ctrl+l is not the same as cmd+k because you can still scroll up and see old history with ctrl+l. If you're tailing a log for example that quickly fills your scroll back cmd+k is invaluable because you know exactly when you last left off. ctrl+l will not do this for you.

Comment: @BjornTipling ⌘+K is a feature of the terminal emulator, and will not work inside tmux... this binding is designed to wipe the static stdout, which is not how tmux ,and other programs like vim/emacs/weechat/mutt, are being displayed.

Comment: +1 for breaking the habit, I can't stop doing it until today. The best thing is to type `clear` instead I guess

Comment: how did you find out to do `ctrl+l`

Comment: @Honey `ctrl+l` has been the traditional clear binding in *nix for decades. If you want to be aware of things like this, you can read the documentation for the tools you use: ie `man bash`

Answer (score 9):

`bind -n C-k send-keys -R \; send-keys C-l \; clear-history`

Got this from [here](http://notes.jerzygangi.com/the-only-way-that-actually-works-to-clear-the-screen-in-tmux/)

Props to him. This works for me just like `Cmd+k` works on the terminal emulator, and works for me on macOS 10.12.5 with iTerm2.

Comment: Works like a charm, even when a command like `tail -f ...` or a server is running!

Comment: Unfortunately, it's in conflict with `nano` cut text command `^K`.

Answer (score 3):

You can add the following lines in your `.tmux.conf`:

```
# clear the current pane
bind -n C-k send-keys C-l \; clear-history
```

Then reload your tmux config. Now you can use your bind key `+k` (e.g.: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>,<kbd>k</kbd>) to clear the current pane.

I don't know the syntax for OSX but I guess you can easily adapt the line.

Comment: I see that `C-l` clears the screen and `clear-history` clears the scrollback buffer. What does the `\;` part do?

Comment: it runs both @NathanLong